# Facebook Graph API - post comment as user

Tags: facebook, access-token, facebook-comments

I want to send comments to wall posts of a fanpage.

```
$facebook->api('/post_id/comments', 'POST', array('access_token' => $auth['access_token'], 'message' => 'my message'));
```

This is working, but when posting with a user who is also admin of the fanpage the comment author ist always set to the fanpage. The access token is the one of the user. The documentation didn´t help. Did anyone this before? Thanks in advance!